# How do I detect screen rotation on android?

Tags: android, android-ndk

i want to detect screen rotation via native.

for a example, when touch event occured, we can detect via /dev/input/event* event device

is this possible ?

i mean, without using java. just use native method.

```
WindowManager wm = (WindowManager)getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
Display disp = wm.getDefaultDisplay();

int rotation = disp.getRotation(); // Android 2.2
Log.i( "Rotation", "rotation : " + rotation );

switch ( rotation )
{
    case Surface.ROTATION_0: 
        Log.i( "Roation", "Portrait : 0" ); 
        break;

    case Surface.ROTATION_90:
        Log.i( "Roation", "Landscape : 90" );
        break;

    case Surface.ROTATION_180:
        Log.i( "Roation", "Portrait : 180" );
        break;

    case Surface.ROTATION_270:
        Log.i( "Roation", "Landscape : 270" );
        break;
}
```

Comment: You cannot access the /dev/input files from an application running on a secured device (ie a consumer device that has not been rooted).

Answer (score 4):

If you're using the NativeActivity infrastructure (it's not obvious from the question), there's a callback `onConfigurationChanged` in struct `ANativeActivityCallbacks`, which is made available to you as a part of a `ANativeActivity` object, which is pointed to by `activity` within the `android_app` structure, which is a parameter to your `android_main`.

Just reset the callback on startup to your function:

```
void OnConfig(ANativeActivity *ac)
{
    //...
}

state->activity->callbacks->onConfigurationChanged = OnConfig;
```

If you are indeed using NativeActivity, please tag the question with `native-activity`, not just `android-ndk`. There's enough difference of environment to warrant an extra tag.